What is fastest method for finding the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of a (possibly very large) symmetric matrix?
What is the best way to find the extreme eigenvalues - in order to find the spectral radius - of a general real dense symmetric matrix?
Looking at similar questions e.g.: What's the most efficient way to compute the eigenvector of a dense matrix corresponding to the eigenvalue of largest magnitude? it seems that at the time the questions were answered the best choice was Lanczos iteration. I was wondering if there has been any recent significant progress in this area or is it still Lanczos.

Is the matrix sparse or dense?

@BrianBorchers Dense - sorry I should have checked that.

You could try looking into stochastic methods, from what I've seen they appear to be one of the few areas which claim potential substantial performance gains. I'm not an expert in the field though, so you might end up finding to a different conclusion.

As far as I know the other main research area has been in the area of parallelization/raw code performance improvements rather than "numerical method" improvements.
